# Upload file to Nexus with plain Java

Tags: java, rest, curl, jira, nexus

I would like to upload an artifact to Nexus from Java. Because the Java code is running in a Jira plugin I would like to avoid

- including external libraries like Aether, Maven Resolver or Rest client APIs
- calling external programs like Maven or Curl.

For downloading files, I used commons-io from apache which is already present if you use the Atlassian SDK. This works fine. But I am stuck in uploading. I think I need to construct a REST POST request like the following curl one

```
curl -v -F r=inubitdeployment -F hasPom=false -F e=jar -F g=com.test -F a=project -F v=1.0 -F p=jar -F file=@log4j.jar -u User:password http://ik-repository:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content
```

but I do not know how to do this from Java.

Comment: how is the jar file created? does it get created from a maven build ?

Comment: Use the built-in class [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

Comment: @RamanathanGanesan No, it is a zip file that is created outside the Maven/Java world.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Thank you. Could you give me some hints how to use form parameters and how to include the content of a file? I need to rebuild the curl command above, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Sure; please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34409142/2170192

Comment: @AlexShesterov Thank you! Any idea how to supply username and password?